# How to stop image from being pushed off screen?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I have a frame around the area that is selected (it contains Qlabel), and a frame around the buttons/objects by the bottom of the screen. I want my screen to STAY this ratio even if I drag it out or upload a very large image to Qlabel. How do I do this? I tried messing around with the "minimum size" for the bottom frame but that did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Qt Designer, check the "scalable" feature in Qlabel.
Also to make it expandable, make sure you properly set the layout of the frame.